# Schema related problems with H2 embedded database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am building a Java Swing Desktop app and I have a problem with the database. After I made ​​the schema "studenti" and table "studenti.ocjene_studenata" in sql file, when I start the program, I get the following message. What exactly would be a problem? I think that I all configured correctly. I will show the message f error,the xml configuration app,sql file and annotations the variables. Thanks a lot!

```
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create table studenti.ocjene_studenata (ID integer generated by default as identity, godina_studiranja integer, ime_studenta varchar(255), baze_podataka integer, matematika integer, napredne_baze_podataka integer, objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_2 integer, objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_1 integer, osnove_programiranja integer, programiranje integer, ocjena_mature integer, prezime_studenta varchar(255), prosjek double, primary key (ID))
kol 18, 2014 7:05:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Schema "STUDENTI" not found; SQL statement:

    create table studenti.ocjene_studenata (
        ID integer generated by default as identity,
        godina_studiranja integer,
        ime_studenta varchar(255),
        baze_podataka integer,
        matematika integer,
        napredne_baze_podataka integer,
        objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_2 integer,
        objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_1 integer,
        osnove_programiranja integer,
        programiranje integer,
        ocjena_mature integer,
        prezime_studenta varchar(255),
        prosjek double,
        primary key (ID)
    ) [90079-171]
kol 18, 2014 7:05:47 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
kol 18, 2014 7:05:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 90079, SQLState: 90079
kol 18, 2014 7:05:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Schema "STUDENTI" not found; SQL statement:
insert into studenti.ocjene_studenata (ID, godina_studiranja, ime_studenta, baze_podataka, matematika, napredne_baze_podataka, objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_2, objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_1, osnove_programiranja, programiranje, ocjena_mature, prezime_studenta, prosjek) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [90079-171]
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Schema "STUDENTI" not found; SQL statement:
insert into studenti.ocjene_studenata (ID, godina_studiranja, ime_studenta, baze_podataka, matematika, napredne_baze_podataka, objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_2, objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_1, osnove_programiranja, programiranje, ocjena_mature, prezime_studenta, prosjek) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [90079-171]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:881)
    at hr.tvz.programiranje.baza.DatabaseUtils.spremiRezultate(DatabaseUtils.java:18)
    at hr.tvz.programiranje.java.swing.glavni.GlavniOkvir$3.actionPerformed(GlavniOkvir.java:177)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Schema "STUDENTI" not found; SQL statement:
insert into studenti.ocjene_studenata (ID, godina_studiranja, ime_studenta, baze_podataka, matematika, napredne_baze_podataka, objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_2, objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_1, osnove_programiranja, programiranje, ocjena_mature, prezime_studenta, prosjek) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [90079-171]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(IdentityGenerator.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2936)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3447)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:818)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:822)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875)
    ... 38 more

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="HibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<class>hr.tvz.programiranje.java.podaci.Podaci</class>
<properties>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/uspjehStudenata"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>

create schema studenti;
create table studenti.ocjene_studenata(
ID INT generated always as identity,
ime_studenta varchar(300) not null,
prezime_studenta varchar (300) not null,
godina_studiranja int not null,
ocjena_mature int not null,
prosjek decimal(3,2) not null,
matematika int not null,
programiranje int not null,
objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_1 int not null,
objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_2 int not null,
osnove_programiranja int not null,
baze_podataka int not null,
napredne_baze_podataka int not null,
primary key(ID)
);

@Entity
@Table(name="studenti.ocjene_studenata")
public class Podaci {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "ime_studenta")
    private String imeStudent;

    @Column(name = "prezime_studenta")
    private String prezimeStudent;

    @Column(name = "godina_studiranja")
    private int godinaStudiranjaInt;

    @Column(name = "ocjena_mature")
    private int ocjenaMatureInt;

    @Column(name = "prosjek")
    private double prosjekDbl;

    @Column(name = "matematika")
    private int ocjMatematika1Int;

    @Column(name = "programiranje")
    private int ocjProgramiranjeInt;

    @Column(name = "objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_1")
    private int ocjOOPIInt;

    @Column(name = "objektno_orijentirano_programiranje_2")
    private int ocjOOPIIInt;

    @Column(name = "osnove_programiranja")
    private int ocjOPInt;

    @Column(name = "baze_podataka")
    private int ocjBPInt;

    @Column(name = "napredne_baze_podataka")
    private int ocjNBPInt;
```

Comment: What is your DB url?

Comment: jdbc:h2:~/uspjehStudenata

Comment: Actually, update your question with content of hibernate configuration file.

Comment: All my configuration you can read from this file, aren't you?
Look at xml file.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, may I know how did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check this out:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/3ZL1GCcDv9M

It's got a good account of a person creating a new schema, having errors due to case sensitivity in the schema name, and resolving them. He also provides the various errors that you get relating to schema naming with different scenarios.

His final solution is actually at the bottom of the thread, but I thought the information in the first section might help your particular case more.

Final solution from thread:

> To help someone else from falling in the same trap I've fallen into 
>   (no matter how improbable that would be) here's a small explanation. 
>   The library I used to connect to databases was sending the remaining 
>   values found in a connection-info map to JDBC getConnection as 
>   properties. I kept the schema name for specific statements in the 
>   "schema" key for internal purpose only. On other databases I've tested
>   my project with, this wasn't a problem, but H2 is coincidentally using
>   the same "schema" key from the connection properties to set the schema
>   to be used with that connection. As this value wasn't properly quoted,
>   it threw the appropriate error. I was totally confused as I assumed 
>   that error was coming from the create table statement I was sending.

Comment: as improbable as it may sound, but I am the occurrence of that improbable chance, this post was the solution to my problem!